# jQuery multiple selectors with dot notation?

Tags: jquery, xml, jquery-selectors

OK. I'm somewhat of a noob... but not that noob-ish. :)

I desire to accomplish a find() in jQuery that has a similar result of dot notation or "&&". Here is an example (which does not work):

```
data.find("continent_country[id = 'us'].state[id = 'in']").each(function(){
// what to do
}
```

or

```
data.find("continent_country[id = 'us'] && state[id = 'in']").each(function(){
// what to do
}
```

I have been told to try a comma, like so:

```
data.find("continent_country[id = 'us'], state[id = 'in']").each(function(){
// what to do
}
```

... but that returns the wrong items.

My XML looks like this:

```
    <continent_country id="us" name="U.S.">
        <state id="al" name="Alabama"> 
            <city url="" name="auburn"/>
            <city url="" name="birmingham"/>
            <city url="" name="dothan"/>
            <city url="" name="florence / muscle shoals"/>
            <city url="" name="gadsden-anniston"/>
            <city url="" name="huntsville / decatur"/>
            <city url="" name="mobile"/>
            <city url="" name="montgomery"/>
            <city url="" name="tuscaloosa"/> 
        </state>
        <state>//more states</states>
    </continent_country>
    </continent_country id="eu" name="Europe">
        <state>//more states</states>
    </continent_country>
```

Some states/provinces/countries share the same id, which is why I would like to find a state in a specified continent_country.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Have you thougt of seperating the selection ? Like first you get all the every continent-country with us and out of that selection you again filter everything with in ?

Comment: I did that originally, but needed a "one line solution". The child-selector ">" worked perfectly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i think you want the child notation:

http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/

something like

```
data.find('continent_country[id = 'us'] > state[id='in']).each(function(){
   //do your stuff here
}
```

Comment: wow 3 downvotes?  what is wrong with people? this is exactly what the op wanted!

Answer (score 1):

You could just use the `add()` method which adds more elements to the selection based on a new selector, e.g.

```
data.find("continent_country[id = 'us']").add("state[id = 'in']").each(function(){
    // what to do
}
```

Comment: But this way still works. Just because there are *other* ways, it does not mean this approach is wrong

Comment: It is not the best approach since you call extra method

Comment: swings and roundabouts really because although it's an extra method, the selectors are simpler. We're talking about milliseconds of difference here. Are *you* perceptive enough to tell the difference..?

Comment: When did I talk about performance ? No matter, asker wants "to find a state in a specified continent_country", add method is not the answer.

Comment: You're talking about my answer being worse 'because it's an extra method' what could that mean except in terms of performance? How else could using an extra method be worse? Just because you didn't *mention* the word 'performance', that doesn't mean it wasn't implied. And I refute your statement, the add() method is one of many answers that will work, it's just not the same as your answer

Comment: I repeat, the asker wants "to find a state IN a specified continent_country"

Comment: Ok, I guess I'm too used to working with HTML where IDs are always unique. add() would work where all ids are unique, but could cause issues if IDs are not unique.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use the `:has` selector, the `.has` function, or select the closest `continent_country` above the state. Here's the `has` function, which is probably the most efficient.

```
data.find("continent_country[id='us']").has("state[id='in']")
```

That's assuming you want to get the `<continent_country>` elements... if I misunderstood and you want to get the `<state>` elements, use a space:

```
data.find("continent_country[id='us'] state[id='in']")
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you try the `.has()` method?

```
data.find("continent_country[id = 'us']").has("state[id = 'in']").each(function(){
// what to do
}
```

That should work.

Answer (score -1):

If you want a state inside a country you should use a [descendant selector](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/) `continent_country[id='us'] state[id='in']`

Or a [child selector](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/) : `continent_country[id='us'] > state[id='in']`

You should learn more about [jquery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)